# Join subquery with min

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm pulling my hair out over a subquery that I'm using to avoid about 100 duplicates (out of about 40k records).  The records that are duplicated are showing up because they have 2 dates in h2.datecreated for a valid reason, so I can't just scrub the data.

I'm trying to get only the earliest date to return.  The first subquery (that starts with "select distinct address_id", with the MIN) works fine on it's own...no duplicates are returned.  So it would seem that the left join (or just plain join...I've tried that too) couldn't possibly see the second h2.datecreated, since it doesn't even show up in the subquery.  But when I run the whole query, it's returning 2 values for some ipc.mfgid's, one with the h2.datecreated that I want, and the other one that I don't want.

I know it's got to be something really simple, or something that just isn't possible.  It really seems like it should work!  This is MSSQL.  Thanks!

```
select distinct ipc.mfgid as IPC, h2.datecreated,
case when ad.Address is null
then ad.buildingname end as Address, cast(trace.name as varchar) 
    + '-' + cast(trace.Number       as varchar) as ONT, 
 c.ACCOUNT_Id,
case when h.datecreated is not null then h.datecreated
     else  h2.datecreated end as Install
from equipmentjoin as ipc
left join historyjoin as h on ipc.id = h.EQUIPMENT_Id 
   and h.type like 'add'
left join circuitjoin as c on ipc.ADDRESS_Id = c.ADDRESS_Id 
           and c.GRADE_Code like '%hpna%'
join (select distinct address_id, equipment_id,  
     min(datecreated) as datecreated, comment
     from history where comment like 'MAC: 5%' group by equipment_id, address_id, comment)
          as h2 on c.address_id = h2.address_id
left join (select car.id, infport.name, carport.number, car.PCIRCUITGROUP_Id
     from circuit as car (NOLOCK)  
     join port as carport (NOLOCK) on car.id = carport.CIRCUIT_Id
      and carport.name like 'lead%'
      and car.GRADE_Id = 29 
     join circuit as inf (NOLOCK) on car.CCIRCUITGROUP_Id = inf.PCIRCUITGROUP_Id
     join port as infport (NOLOCK) on inf.id = infport.CIRCUIT_Id
     and infport.name like '%olt%' )
 as trace on c.ccircuitgroup_id = trace.pcircuitgroup_id
join addressjoin as ad (NOLOCK) on ipc.address_id = ad.id
```

Comment: Ah, `NOLOCK`, otherwise known as the mysterious "I'm feeling lucky" turbo button.

Comment: Our database apparently has issues, and we've found that when we don't use NOLOCK, everything except the query that's running comes to a halt.  I prefer not to be the person that takes down order-entry and such. :)

Comment: Ok, well as long as it's also okay that these queries yield missing or duplicate data, or cause problems like the data movement error...

Comment: Some tips for your query: Don't use `CAST(something AS VARCHAR)` without giving it a length (use `VARCHAR(50)` for example). You should also try the function `ISNULL` instead of `CASE WHEN something IS NULL THEN..`. The `DISTINCT` is not necessary if you are already doing a `GROUP BY`, get rid of it. Are you sure that your subquery returns one value per `asdress_id`?

Comment: Also, you don't need `distinct` *and* `group by`. And about varchar without length: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Comment: I've tried with and without distinct, 'where comment like 'MAC: 5'' on the join instead of in the subquery, and lots of other changes that I don't remember, and I still get 2 values for some ipc.mfgid on some records that have 2 h2.datecreated.  And I'll look into the varchar.

Comment: @BlairBrown - Those tips are just to make a better code, they are not gonna fix this particular problem. Then again, are you sure that your subquery returns one value per `adress_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This subqery:

```
select distinct address_id, equipment_id,  
 min(datecreated) as datecreated, comment
 from history where comment like 'MAC: 5%' group by equipment_id, address_id, comment
```

Probably will return multiple rows because the comment is not guaranteed to be the same.

Try this instead:

```
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT TOP 1 H2.DateCreated, H2.Comment -- H2.Equipment_id wasn't used
   FROM History H2
   WHERE
      H2.Comment LIKE 'MAC: 5%'
      AND C.Address_ID = H2.Address_ID
   ORDER BY DateCreated
) H2
```

Switch that to `OUTER APPLY` in case you want rows that don't have a matching desired history entry.

Comment: I've never seen CROSS APPLY.  Is that instead of the JOIN to the subquery?

Comment: Sweet!  I think the OUTER APPLY does what I need it to!  Now I need to figure out *how* it's doing what it's doing. :)

Comment: Using a derived table with @Aaron's solutions would work just fine as well. The SQL 2000 version suffers from duplicate key confusion, though (it's hard to add additional ORDER BY keys to it).

Answer (score 2):

The typical approach to only getting the lowest row is one of the following. You didn't bother to specify what version of SQL Server you're using, what you want to do with ties, and I have little interest to try to work this into your complex query, so I'll show you an abstract simplification for different versions.

**SQL Server 2000**

```
SELECT x.grouping_column, x.min_column, x.other_columns ...
FROM dbo.foo AS x
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT grouping_column, min_column = MIN(min_column)
  FROM dbo.foo GROUP BY grouping_column
) AS y  
ON x.grouping_column = y.grouping_column
AND x.min_column = y.min_column;
```

**SQL Server 2005+**

```
;WITH x AS
(
   SELECT grouping_column, min_column, other_columns,
     rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY min_column)
   FROM dbo.foo
)
SELECT grouping_column, min_column, other_columns
FROM x
WHERE rn = 1;
```